# Not able to send mail from ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfmail, coldfusion-administrator

In my application I am using ColdFusion 10. I am not able to send any mail using the `cfmail` tag.

When I log into the administrator and click on the Undelivered Mail button, it is throwing the following error:

```
Error retrieving markup for element mailBody : Client verification failure. [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL parameters to see more information]

Error invoking CFC /CFIDE/administrator/mail/undeliveredmail.cfc : Client verification failure. [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL parameters to see more information]
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a bad CF installation. The admin should not be throwing errors, this looks like a permissions issue at first glance.

Have you tried setting all the params within the cfmail tag (eg, mailserver, username, pwd) instead of using the values set in CFadmin?

Do you get an error when you create a single CFM page with just a CFMAIL tag in it?

You need to ensure your CF install is up to date with all the hotfixes and that they are installed correctly.

see http://forums.adobe.com/thread/884947

or post the error message you are getting when you use your CFMAIL tag